# Installing Python 3.7.4 x64bit on my windows machine

Tags: python

I am attempting to create a Flask server in Sublime text editor 3, so I installed Python 3.7.4 on my Windows x64 machine and clicked the "add to path" tick mark upon installation.

When I attempt to run my code I get:

`'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Ok, so I double check my path and sure enough it is correct. It is installed under users/appdata/etc.

When I run the windows `cmd` and enter `python`, it tells me it is installed. I saved my file as `main.py`. I am stumped, any advice?

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you running?  Please edit your question to include this vital information required before an answer can be submitted.  You should also provide the contents of your PATH system variable (system and user).

Comment: Restart your PC.

Comment: Does using `py -3` work? Most likely a PATH issue.

Answer (score 0):

Either add a shebang directive as the very first first line to your main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

or provide the path to main.py as an argument to python:

```
> python "C:\Path\to\main.py"
```